# Apply function to different groups in same column

Tags: r, function, apply

I have some daily temperature data from 10 different sites in 3 different streams. Some sites have missing dates that need to be filled in with NA's
How can I apply the code below to each site A-J so every site no longer has missing dates. Some sites are both missing the same dates.

```
sorted_data = SiteA[order(SiteA$Date),]
data_length = length(sorted_data$Date)
time_min = sorted_data$Date[1]
time_max = sorted_data$Date[data_length]
all_dates = seq(time_min, time_max, by="day")
all_dates_frame = data.frame(list(Date=all_dates))
SiteA= merge(all_dates_frame, sorted_data, all=T)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Take a look at `?tapply` and `?aggregate`.

Comment: I think that's is the way to go but I'm stuck on the specifics. I'm reading up on aggregate and the other functions similar to apply. I'm not sure how to tell R to apply it to every site based on name

Comment: reproducible sample data that shows the structure of your data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap that code into a function and apply it, but there are other problems with the code and it's also not a statistically valid imputation methodology (unless you know something I don't about this particular case).

This is what I recommend:

```
require(data.table) # to avoid trouble using rbind on dates and for speed
require(RRF)

# Simulate the data in question 
siteA <- data.table(Stream = c(1,1,1), Date = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+1, NA), site = 1)
siteB <- data.table(Stream = c(2,2,2), Date = c(Sys.Date()-1, Sys.Date()+1, NA), site = 2)
siteC <- data.table(Stream = c(3,3,3), Date = c(Sys.Date()-2, NA, Sys.Date()), site = 3)
siteD <- data.table(Stream = c(1,1,1), Date = c(NA, Sys.Date()+1, NA), site = 4)
siteE <- data.table(Stream = c(2,2,2), Date = c(Sys.Date(), NA, NA), site = 5)
siteF <- data.table(Stream = c(3,3,3), Date = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+1, NA), site = 6)
siteG <- data.table(Stream = c(1,1,1), Date = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()-1, NA), site = 7)
siteH <- data.table(Stream = c(1,1,1), Date = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()-3, NA), site = 8)
siteI <- data.table(Stream = c(1,1,1), Date = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+1, NA), site = 9)
siteJ <- data.table(Stream = c(1,1,1), Date = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+1, NA), site = 10)


# Combine data and impute date
DT <- rbind(siteA,siteB,siteC,siteD,siteE,siteF,siteG,siteH,siteI,siteJ)
DT <- DT[, Date:=as.factor(as.character(Date))]

DT <- na.roughfix(DT)
DT

    Stream       Date site
 1:      1 2016-06-14    1
 2:      1 2016-06-15    1
 3:      1 2016-06-14    1
 4:      2 2016-06-13    2
 5:      2 2016-06-15    2
 6:      2 2016-06-14    2
 7:      3 2016-06-12    3
 8:      3 2016-06-14    3
 9:      3 2016-06-14    3
10:      1 2016-06-14    4
11:      1 2016-06-15    4
12:      1 2016-06-14    4
13:      2 2016-06-14    5
14:      2 2016-06-14    5
15:      2 2016-06-14    5
16:      3 2016-06-14    6
17:      3 2016-06-15    6
18:      3 2016-06-14    6
19:      1 2016-06-14    7
20:      1 2016-06-13    7
21:      1 2016-06-14    7
22:      1 2016-06-14    8
23:      1 2016-06-11    8
24:      1 2016-06-14    8
25:      1 2016-06-14    9
26:      1 2016-06-15    9
27:      1 2016-06-14    9
28:      1 2016-06-14   10
29:      1 2016-06-15   10
30:      1 2016-06-14   10
    Stream       Date site
```

`na.roughfix` is, as the name implies a rough -- but widely used and statistically acceptable -- imputation method. If you want something even better (at the expense of taking a little longer to setup and run) try `mice` or even better `amelia`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. My data is different from your code because the NA's for missing dates do not exist. The dates just skip (e.g. 6/13/2016,6/15/2016). Ideally the function would look at the date range for each site, create rows with missing dates,insert NA's for the temp data columns where missing dates exist. Thanks again.